# Find commonalities between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to compare two dataframes with different dimension

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': ['20', '14', '56', '28'],
                   'Weight': [59, 29, 73, 56],
                   'Height' : [185, 160, 175, 180]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Age': ['20', '14', '56', '12', '10', '30', '28'],
                    'Weight': [59, 29, 73, 56, 68, 48, 50],
                    'Height' : [185, 155, 170, 160, 155, 177, 172]})
```

I want to find find shared data points in df from df1 vice versa and create separate dataframes so looking for output to be like this:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'Age':['20','14','56','28'],
                          'Weight': [59, 29, 73,56],
                          'Height' : [185, 160, 175, 180]})

df1_result = pd.DataFrame({'Age':['20','14','56','28'],
                           'Weight': [59, 29, 73, 56],
                           'Height': [185, 160, 170, 172]})
```

I'm trying to use Age and Weight as criteria to look for shared data point

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join with `rename` columns names:

```
df1 = df.merge(df1, on=['Age','Weight'])

df_result = df1.rename(columns={'Height_x':'Height'})[df.columns]
print (df_result)
  Age  Weight  Height
0  20      59     185
1  14      29     160
2  56      73     175

df1_result = df1.rename(columns={'Height_y':'Height'})[df.columns]
print (df1_result)
  Age  Weight  Height
0  20      59     185
1  14      29     155
2  56      73     170
```

Or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) by both columns:

```
ind1 = df.set_index(['Age','Weight']).index
ind2 = df1.set_index(['Age','Weight']).index

df_result = df[ind1.isin(ind2)]
print (df_result)
  Age  Weight  Height
0  20      59     185
1  14      29     160
2  56      73     175

df1_result = df1[ind2.isin(ind1)]
print (df1_result)
  Age  Weight  Height
0  20      59     185
1  14      29     155
2  56      73     170
```